# Why build an AST walker instead of having the nodes responsible for their own output?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

Given an AST, what would be the reason behind making a `Walker` class that walks over the tree and does the output, as opposed to giving each `Node` class a `compile()` method and having it responsible for its own output?

Here are some examples:
[Doctrine 2](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/SqlWalker.php) (an ORM) uses a `SQLWalker` to walk over an AST and generate SQL from nodes.
[Twig](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Node/If.php) (a templating language) has the nodes output their own code (this is an `if` statement node).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly because of old literature and available tools. Experimenting with both methods you can easily find that AST traversal produces very slow and convoluted code. Moreover, code separated from immediate syntax doesn't resemble it anymore. It's very much like supporting two synchronized code bases, which is always a bad idea. Debugging, maintenance become difficult.

Of course, it can be also difficult to process semantics on the nodes unless you have a well designed state machine. In fact you are never worse than having to traverse AST after the fact, because it's just one particular case of processing semantics on nodes.

You can often hear that AST traversal allows for implementation of multiple semantics for the same syntax. In reality you would never want that, not only because it's rarely needed, but also for performance reasons. And frankly, there is no difficulty in writing separate syntax for a different semantics. The results were always better when both designed together.

And finally, in every non-trivial task, get syntax parsed is the easiest part, getting semantics correct and process actions fast is a challenge. Focusing on AST is approaching the task backwards.

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer better. I don't know a ton on the topic, but this just seems more reasonable. It just seems like ast traversal over complicates things.

Comment: What do you mean by "slow and convoluted code"? Please take a look at, say, Scrap Your Boilerplate library (for Haskell), I bet you'd change your opinion on AST transformers.

Answer (score 9):

Using a separate `Walker` for code generation avoids combinatorial explosion in the number of AST node classes as the number of target representations increases. When a `Walker` is responsible for code generation, you can retarget it to a different representation just by altering the `Walker` class. But when the AST nodes themselves are responsible for compilation, you need a different version of each node for each separate target representation.

Answer (score 0):

To have support for a feature that the "internal AST walker" doesn't have.

For example, there are several ways to trasnverse a "hierarchical" or "tre" structure,
like "walk thru the leafs first", or "walk thru the branches first".

Or if the nodes siblings have a sort index, and you want to "walk" / "visit" them decremantally by their index, instead of incrementally.

If the AST class or structure you have only works with one method, you may want to use another method using your custom "walker" / "visitor".